# How to get the app to run in 'Scaled Mode' on iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, iphone-6

I am trying to create a webview app for iPhone. I select iPhone as device while creating the project in Xcode 6 but the size of the device in main story board is larger than iPhone devices (it might be defaulted to iPhone 6). I didn't have this problem with Xcode 5.

How can I change it to iPhone 5 size or fit my webview to all these sizes? I use Scale to Fit feature but it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove launch screen and launch images for iPhone 6 and 6 plus from the project if they are added

Answer (score 2):

Remove launch screen and launch images for iPhone 6 and 6 plus from the project if they are added and your app will be scaled